# Powershell script to retrieve JSON content that has square bracket in the beginning and the end

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have a Json file, input.json, with a content of

> [
> {
> "id": "1234abc",
> "createdDate":"2021-10-04"
> }
> ]

However, when I use the Powershell script below to retrieve its content, I get nothing in return.

```
$inputread=Get-Content -raw "D:\sourcefolder\input.json" | ConvertFrom-Json
Write-Output "Input is $inputread
```

I got only

```
Input is
```

Please advise me how to get the content of the Json file.

Comment: @user4317867 `ConvertFrom-Json` has no depth parameter.

Comment: @kjyon2 your JSON is not valid, you're missing `"` at the end of the date. Is that the case? Or you just formatted the question wrongly?

Comment: @user4317867, I have scripted it as `$inputread=Get-Content -raw "D:\Sourcefolder\input/json" | ConvertFrom-Json -Depth 5`

However, I got an error saying that

"ConvertFrom-Json: A Parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Depth'. At ...
It is an InvalidArgument: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ParameterBindingException.

Comment: @Vivere, I have updated the Json with the `"`. Thank you for your notice. Can you advise me how can I get the Json content please?

Comment: `[]` are array delimiters. That's a one-element JSON array.

Comment: Deleted my incorrect `-Depth` comment, was thinking of something else! Pipe the `$inputread` to `Get-Member` to see what's the object's type. I tested the sample JSON in a file with multiple lines, I had to remove `-Raw` from `Get-Content` but otherwise everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

the Square brackets indicate that the Json String is an array of objects.
So your variable $Inputread will be an array of objects.

if you use `.GetType()` you can see the BaseType is a Object.Array

```
$inputread.gettype()
```

When you try to Write-Output, you are specifying the whole Array, but not indicating what property you want to output from the Objects within the Array.
at its ugliest you could just do a

```
Write-Output "Input is $($inputread.Id)"
```

but you may find it better to use one of these as they will be more readable.

#Alt 1 - ForEach Loop

```
Foreach($Item in $inputread){
    Write-Output "Input is $($Item.Id)"
}
```

#Alt 2 - Foreach-Object

```
$inputread|%{Write-Output "Input is $($_.Id)"}
```

#Alt 3 - For Loop with $I as Index number

```
$ObjCount = ($inputread|measure).count
for ($I=0;$I -lt $ObjCount;$I++){
    $Obj = $inputread[$I]
    Write-Output "Input is $($Obj.Id)"
}
```